# iOS application control non-ios devices via bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, bluetooth, communication

I want to develop iOS application that is a remote cotrol via bluetooth for the specific product. I try to research related methods for iOS programming, but most people almost said is impossible in iOS. I know iOS allow communication between iOS devices and iOS devices via bluetooth and also support some bluetooth control iOS. But I want to develop iOS application that can control non-iOS device via bluetooth.

Comment: According to the Apple's and iOS Document, its highly impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible - The non iOS device must be an apple approved accessory or MFi Compliant

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if Jailbreaking is an option: you can use BTstack.org to use RFCOMM & L2CAP to talk to remote Bluetooth devices.